# Logic for Grouping number

Tags: java

I am having 1 -10 in different groups A,B and C.
For eg. A-1,A-2,A-3,B-4,C-5,B-6,A-7,C-8,A-9,A,10

I want to make group separately as A, B and C

```
A
1-3,
7,
9-10

B
4,
6

C
5,
8
```

can any one help me with logic..?

Comment: No. 8 is in Group B and C. No other number is in more than one group. Is this an error, or intentional? The text before the block has distinct numbers in the groups. Another question is: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to get you started:

```
String[] items = new String[] {
  "A-1", "B-2", "A-5"
}

// This is the data structure that will receive the final data. The map key is the 
// group name (e.g. "A" for item "A-15") and the map value is a list of numbers that
// have been found for that group. TreeMap is chosen because the groups will be sorted
// alphabetically. If you don't need that, you could also use HashMap.
Map<String, List<Integer>> groups = new TreeMap<String, List<Integer>>();

for (String item : items) {
  // Split the item into the group and the number
  String group = item.substring(0, 1);
  String number = Integer.toString(item.substring(2));

  // See if this group is already registered in our Map
  List<Integer> groupData = groups.get(group);
  if (groupData==null) {
    groupData = new List<Integer>();
    groups.put(group, groupData);
  }

  // Add the number to the data
  groupData.add(number);
}
```

I assume here that your items are always in the form **1 letter dash number**. If it is a bit more complicated than that, you'll want to have a look at regular expressions (see java class Pattern). This is not tested, I let you test it and handle the special cases.

This function will output for `{ "A-1", "A-2", "A-3", "B-2", "A-5" }`:

```
A -> {1, 2, 3, 5}
B -> {2}
```

You'll need to process the resulting number lists if you want to merge consecutive numbers, but that should not be too difficult if you think about it a little while.

Answer (score 0):

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) will help you creating the Data Structure you need:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    String input = "A-1,A-2,A-3,B-4,C-5,B-6,A-7,C-8,A-9,A-10";

    // create multimap
    Map<String, Collection<Integer>> map=Maps.newTreeMap();
    SortedSetMultimap<String, Integer> multimap = Multimaps.newSortedSetMultimap(
        map, new Supplier<SortedSet<Integer>>() {
          public SortedSet<Integer> get() {
              return new TreeSet<Integer>();
          }
    });

    //add data
    Splitter entrySplitter = Splitter.on(',');
    Splitter keyValueSplitter = Splitter.on('=');
    for (String entry : entrySplitter.split(input)) {
        Iterator<String> tokens = keyValueSplitter.split(entry).iterator();
        multimap.put(tokens.next(), Integer.valueOf(tokens.next()));
    }

    // read data
    for (Entry<String, Collection<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()+":");
        printMergedValues(entry.getValue());
    }

}

private static void printMergedValues(Collection<Integer> value) {
    // TODO implement this yourself
}
```

The only thing I left for you is to join the groups

Answer (score 0):

I'd go this way:

```
     String[] input = {"A-1","A-2","A-3","B-4","C-5","B-6","A-7","C-8","A-9"};
     Map<String, Set<Integer>> result = new HashMap<String, Set<Integer>>();
     String[] inputSplit;
     String group;
     Integer groupNumber;
     for (String item : input)
     {
         inputSplit = item.split("-");
         group = inputSplit[0];
         groupNumber = Integer.valueOf( inputSplit[1] );
         if ( result.get(group) == null ) { result.put(group, new HashSet<Integer>()); }
         result.get(group).add(groupNumber);
     }

     for (Map.Entry entry : result.entrySet())
     {
         System.out.println( entry.getKey() + ":"  +  entry.getValue() );
     }
```